# UICollectionView and UICollectionViewCell animate frame

Tags: uicollectionview, jquery-animate, uicollectionviewcell

I have a requirement to animate UICollectionView and UICollectionViewCell frame. The end results is what I but in between there appear to be some phantom cells being mixed in with actual cells being animated. The CV animates to a different size and the CV cells are to match the new size based on settings given to CV's collectionViewLayout.

Here's the starting point:
[image]

Here's how the animation starts to look:
[image]

The end result is as expected:
[image]

My final intent is to do this with a UIViewPropertyAnimator() but you see the same problem even if the animation is triggered with a standard UIView animation.

The main method called is prepareLayout().

```
  internal var theLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    return (buttonsView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout)!
  }

      internal func prepareLayout() {
    let spacing = buttonTheme.spacing * 2.0

//    let theLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    theLayout.invalidateLayout()

    buttonsView.frame = viewModel.frame
    theLayout.itemSize = itemSize
    theLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = spacing
    theLayout.minimumLineSpacing = spacing

    buttonsView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: spacing, left: spacing, bottom: spacing, right: spacing)

//    buttonsView.performBatchUpdates({
      buttonsView.setCollectionViewLayout(theLayout, animated: true)
      self.buttonsView.reloadData()
//    }, completion: nil)

    buttonsView.setCollectionViewLayout(theLayout, animated: true)
  }
```

As can seen, I've been playing around with CV's performBatchUpdates() and setCollectionViewLayout() but to no avail. I need to reloadData() because things like the fontSize change during the animation which will be more important when using UIViewPropertyAnimator().

My cell is a subclass of UICollectionViewCell that has a UIButton in it. The interaction of the button is disabled so I can handle everything in the CV.

Ideas on how to correct this problem are appreciated.

Edit: Jan 26
Here's a public repo that's a stripped down version of the app but illustrates the issue:
https://github.com/Phantom-59/CVAnimatorTest

Comment: I've created a public repo that's essentially a stripped down version of my app that shows the issue; see https://github.com/Phantom-59/CVAnimatorTest

Would appreacite any ideas on correting the problem.